# Why doesnt this run properly?

Tags: java, string

So I've learnt the basics of Java and I'm practising with some newbie projects. Im currently doing this project:
http://codingbat.com/prob/p123384

I dont know why my code doesn't work:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(frontBack("java"));

    }

    public static String frontBack(String str) {

        if (str.length() < 1) {
            return str;
        } else if (str.length() >= 2) {

            char a = str.charAt(0);
            char b = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);

            str.replace(a, b);

        }
        return str;

    }

}
```

It runs but it doesn't swap the front character with the back character. I looked at the solution the website had and it does make sense too me.. much simpler too but why doesn't my code work? Also I don't think im using the return keywords properly...

Answer (score 0):

because you don't set str with new value.

the function [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) return a String.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(frontBack("java"));

    }

    public static String frontBack(String str) {

        if (str.length() < 1) {
            return str;
        } else if (str.length() >= 2) {

            char a = str.charAt(0);
            char b = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);

            str = str.replace(a, b);
            //str = str.replace(b, a); maybe you need it 

        }
        return str;

    }

}
```

Comment: Correct that you need to assign the result of `replace`.  However, `replace` is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Ι agree, It is not the best way. I just fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
return b + str.substring(1, str.length() - 1) + a;
```

str.replace(...) *returns* a String, so (even if it were correct) you would lose the return value.

The method replace replaces coherent matching sequences of characters but you need to replace different values, in two places. replace isn't good for the last character, because this character might occur at an earlier position, so you'd replace there, too.

Usually, you'll also have to consider str.length() == 1; here it happens to fall through and also returns the original string. But it's better to make this explicit in the code:

```
if( str.length() <= 1 ){
    return str;
} else {
    char a = str.charAt(0);
    char b = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
    return b + str.substring(1, str.length() - 1) + a;
}
```

Remember: A String object, once set, *cannot be changed by any method applied to it*. You can assign a new String object to variable holding a String reference.